# How can I tell a Linux Script (ash, not bash) is running "sourced"?

Tags: linux, ash

How can I tell in an ash script if it is running "sourced" or "normal"?  By sourced I mean using the "." or "source" command to launch the script in the current shell.

Comment: One indication that a script is being "sourced" is that `$0` is set to the interpreter path (example: `/bin/bash`) instead of the script path  (example: `/path/to/your/script.sh`), which is normally the case when running an executable script. I'm not sure how reliable is this for your purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if it's the best option (will not work if the script has the same name as the shell), but you can check the first parameter (`$0`). Example:

```
$ cat test.sh
#!/bin/ash
echo "Value: $0"


$ ./test.sh
Value: ./test.sh

$ source test.sh
Value: ash
```

If you want to check if the file was sourced, you can use something like this:

```
#!/bin/ash
case $0 in
    ash) echo "Sourced" ;;
      *) echo "Not sourced" ;;
esac
```

Comment: Not a very good idea. It's not unheard-of to run scripts like "bash test.sh".

Comment: Yes, but if it is sourced you still get `bash`/`ash`

Comment: The point is, if you use the logic "`$0==bash` implies the script is being sourced", that will produce the wrong answer when someone does `bash ./test.sh` (and obviously it holds equally for ash and other shells).

Comment: but you can still check if `$0` (or `$BASH_SOURCE`) ends with `.sh`, which is a bit better, as long as nobody messes up with the script names of course.

Comment: This trick is only for my personal use and I am profoundly unlikely to ever use `ash test.sh`.  I will, however remember this is a poor trick for production. Thanks @SALEM.

Comment: Oddly enough, this doesn't work as expected.  `if [ "$0" -ne "/bin/ash" ]; then echo "Run me SOURCED."; exit; fi` tries to execute the script itself again and complains with an "out of range: error.  Oh well.  I didn't pick ash.  The system designers did.